# Facebook SDK collecting user information and friends

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to use the Facebook SDK to collect user information and friends. Ideally I would like to use FBRequest as opposed to FBConnectionRequest. As detailed on the Facebook Developer page it says to use FBRequest for multiple requests for information and Connection for one only.

> An FBRequest object may be reused to issue multiple connections to
>   Facebook. However each FBRequestConnection instance will manage one
>   connection.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBRequest)

I have currently setup a FBRequestConnection as follows which is working fine:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id<FBGraphUser> user, NSError *error)
```

What I am trying to achieve is collect the user information such as name, username and email address etc (which works fine with the above, I have already handled the session/with permissions for this.

Now I need to change the connection so that it is an FBRequest, this way I can use the following delegate method:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
```

Then within the delegate method, I will call a second requestForMyFriends and handle both lots of information in a single method. My creation of the request is completed in within my login block and is simply this:

```
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/?fields=name,picture"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:NULL];
```

Firstly, is this the correct way to approach this?

Secondly, I receive an error when it gets to the FBRequest so there must be an issue here but I am unsure what is incorrect. I cannot find further information on Facebook, but if anyone can point me in the right direction of a tutorial using this method that would also help.

EDIT --
Error 
[image]

EDIT 2 -- Additional code sample

```
// TODO : logging can be turned off/removed
[FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, nil]];

NSDictionary *params = @{ @"fields" : @[ @"name", @"picture" ] };
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                          parameters:params
                                          HTTPMethod:nil]; //nil will default on GET
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {}];
```

Comment: @GabrielePetronella - updated, although the error doesn't tell me much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error since you cannot pass an empty completion handler block to the method.

The code below is tested and it works as intended.

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/?fields=name,picture"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}];
```

Comment: Unfortunately the first line of the above codes errors and is not formatted correctly?

Comment: I have tried without the first line, and included the parameters as nil as I already have an access token which can be used at this point. This does cause an error though, included in the question but does not display much towards help...

Comment: sorry I made a typo, now it should compiler properly.

Comment: I believe the error may come from the fact that we are not providing a completion handler. Try to pass an empty block instead of `nil`, like in my example above.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I get a SIGBART - reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: The error occurs immediately after the last line of the above code.

Comment: well it's a start, you're not getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` anymore. The error you're getting now is due to the fact that you're using a `NSArray` where a `NSString` is requested.

Comment: I don't see any `NSArray` declaration in the above code, probably the error is not due to what you've posted. Can you update it?

Comment: I know strange right. I wonder if it is because of the dictionary format I have never seen them created like this (your example above). I have pasted exactly what I use to create the connection, it is your sample with the additional logging but that has always worked without an issue. The code does not reach my FBRequestDelegate methods so cannot be those. It falls over instantly afte the request startWith... My original code is commented out, this partly works I get the NSLog result back but the delegate methods are not being run? I have set the FBRequestDelegate in the header file...

Comment: Ok I found out the problem(s). You cannot pass an array as parameter (my bad) and that caused the last crash. Concerning the first crash you were getting, it was due to the `NULL` completion handler block. I edited my answer with working (and tested) code.

Comment: This creates the request but the delegate methods are not being called when the request actually runs, it is the FBRequestDelegate but the methods are not called, any thoughts?

Comment: That API is block-bases, so the block will be called, not the `FBRequestDelegate`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the delegate methods called instead? The reason is that I want to use the delegate methods to handle the data for profile picture/name and separately a request for friends. These can be handled in the delegate method with an if statement, as opposed to having an extremely large block base which does the same thing.

Comment: You can call the delegate method from inside the block

Comment: Like this? [self request:request didLoad:result]; ?

Comment: Where are you getting `request` from? You cannot get a `FBRequest` object out of a `FBConnectionRequest`. I don't see what's the difference of having a block with an if statement, as opposed to a method. If it really bothers you, just create a method `-(void)handleSuccessfulRequest:(id)result` and call it from your block. Conceptually there's not difference.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a user permission with with **READ Access** only

```
    let permissionsDesired = ["email", "public_profile", "user_friends"]

    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()
    facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(permissionsDesired,
                                        fromViewController: sender)
        { (facebookLogin:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError:NSError!) -> Void in

            if facebookError != nil
            {
                print("Facebook login. Error: \(facebookError.localizedDescription)")

                self.delegate?.permissionResults(false)
            }
            else
            {
                   // access granted, you can start 
                   //requesting user data now
                   self.requestUserInfo()
            }
    }
```

Below is how to get User Data **after** you have the user has granted permission

```
func requestUserInfo( )
{

    let graphPath:String            = "me"
    let httpMethod:String           = "GET"
    var listOfrequest:String = String("about")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",age_range")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",bio")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",birthday")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",context")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",cover")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",currency")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",devices")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",education")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",email")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",favorite_athletes")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",favorite_teams")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",first_name")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",gender")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",hometown")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",id")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",inspirational_people")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",installed")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",install_type")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",is_shared_login")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",is_verified")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",languages")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",last_name")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",link")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",locale")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",location")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",meeting_for")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",middle_name")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",name")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",name_format")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",payment_pricepoints")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",picture")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",political")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",public_key")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",quotes")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",relationship_status")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",religion")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",security_settings")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",shared_login_upgrade_required_by")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",significant_other")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",sports")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",test_group")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",third_party_id")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",timezone")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",updated_time")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",verified")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",video_upload_limits")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",viewer_can_send_gift")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",website")
    listOfrequest = listOfrequest .stringByAppendingString(",work")

    let params:[NSObject:AnyObject] =  ["fields": listOfrequest ]

    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: graphPath,
                                                            parameters: params,
                                                            HTTPMethod: httpMethod)


    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler(
        { (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, userData:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

            if (error == nil)
            {
               print(userData) 
            }
            else
            {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                //Handle error here
            }
    })

}//eom
```