# Requesting user information and Friends from Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am looking to combine a call to Facebook Graph API. I would like to collect both the friends and profile information in one go.

I have also raised a separate question issue here - [Facebook SDK collecting user information and friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623536/facebook-sdk-collecting-user-information-and-friends)

What is the correct/easiest way to create a Facebook Graph request for both these parts?

The user is logged in with this permission array:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_birthday", @"user_location", @"email"];
```

I am then trying to create a graph connection to get information 'such as' username, email, friend list. Ideally I want to do this in one FBRequest, rather than separate FBRequestConnection(s). How can I accomplish this? I have looked through the Facebook SDK information and cannot see how to do this, how can I find out more information on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of this information in one API call to:

```
/me?fields=id,username,email,friends
```

I'm not sure of the syntax for iOS.

If you want more data about your friends, you can specify fields through [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/), like this:

```
/me?fields=id,username,email,friends.fields(id,name,username,birthday)
```

Comment: My question is more on the code used to create the Facebook Graph (FBRequest) instead of using seperate FBRequestConnections. Also how to handle the delegate methods of FBRequest to see what information is being received.

Comment: Yeah, I can't help you with that. I've never coded one line of objective-c.